# How to develop for player 10.1 beta?

Tags: flash, events, sample, microphone

I've been waiting for the day that flash gets access to raw audio data. That day is now, but i'm not sure how to get 10.1 working in CS4. I have 10.1 installed and a function bound to the mic's "SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA" but my "micSampleData" function is not being called.

```
var mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.MICROPHONE);
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
mic.setLoopBack(true);
mic.rate = 44;

function micActivity(event:ActivityEvent):void
{
 trace("micActivity: " + event);
}

function micStatus(event:StatusEvent):void
{
 trace("micStatus: " + event);
}

function micSampleData(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
 trace("micSampleData: " + event);
}

mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, micActivity);
mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, micStatus);
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to test in your browser until a standalone player for 10.1 is released. The current betas are for the browser plugins only.